# twitter bootstrap popovers for R shiny app - html is interpreted as text content - why?

Tags: javascript, r, twitter-bootstrap, shiny

I want to add popovers from the twitter bootstrap framework to a shiny app. Everything works fine, except
 that the `html: true` tag does not have an effect:

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Header"),

  sidebarPanel(
    actionButton("btn-1", "Go!")
  ),

  mainPanel(
    tags$head(
      tags$script('
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#btn-1")
                  .popover({html: true, 
                            title: "Button 1", 
                            content: "<h1>Press</h1> for some action", 
                            trigger: "hover"
                  });
          });   
      ')
    )
  )
))
```

[image]

The same code as pure HTML / JS (without the shiny part) just works fine:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
             $("#btn-1")
                .popover({html: true, 
                          title: "Button 1", 
                          content: "<h1>Press</h1> for some action",
                          trigger: "hover",
                          delay: {show: 100, hide: 100} 
                });

    }); 
</script>

<button id="btn-1" type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
```

[image]

Any ideas? I am not too familiar with the bootstrap framework, but may it have to do with the version that is included by shiny?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tags` enviroment carries out HTML escaping. In order to prevent this on your html string you need to mark it with `HTML`.

```
yourStr <-   '$(document).ready(function(){
                      $("#btn-1")
                      .popover({html: true, 
                      title: "Button 1", 
                      content: "<h1>Press</h1> for some action", 
                      trigger: "hover"
                      });
                      });   
                      '
```

and use the following in your script

```
tags$head(tags$script(HTML(yourStr)))
```