# Shiny: adding addPopover to actionLink

Tags: r, twitter-bootstrap, shiny, popover

I want to include a small "Help" actionLink (next to a "Render" actionButton) that acts as a popover (see [here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#popovers)). Here's my code:

server.R:

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  sidebarPanel( 
    actionButton("renderButton", "Render"),
    actionLink("link", "Help") ),
  mainPanel()
))
```

ui.R:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
   # ... dealing with renderButton ...
   output$link <- renderUI({
   addPopover(session=session, id=output$link, title="", 
              content="Testing.", placement = "bottom",
              trigger = "click", options = NULL)
   })
})
```

Right now, the actionLink shows up on the sidebar, but clicking on it has no effect. Any tips? I think it may have to do with the id in addPopover, but I haven't found many examples to provide a framework. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956894/twitter-bootstrap-popovers-for-r-shiny-app-html-is-interpreted-as-text-content), but I want to deal with the popover in server.R, not ui.R. Can it be done this way, or should I just make the popover in ui.R?

Comment: How about using [shinyBS](https://ebailey78.github.io/shinyBS/) package?

Comment: That's what this is, I just can't figure out how to implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `?Tooltips_and_Popovers`:

> There must be at least one shinyBS component in the UI of your app in
>   order for the necessary dependencies to be loaded. Because of this,
>   addTooltip and addPopover will not work if they are the only shinyBS
>   components in your app.

To get the pop over to work, you can change your `actionButton` into a `bsButton`, and modify `server.R` to only contain the call to `addPopover`. The `id` argument to `addPopover` also needs to be changed to refer to the id of the ui object you want the pop over to appear on, in your case `"link"`, the id of the `actionLink` .

Here's the modified example code in a self-contained code chunk:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

runApp(
  # Ui
  list(ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Test App"),

    sidebarPanel( 
      bsButton("renderButton", "Render"),
      actionLink("link", "Help") ),

    mainPanel("Hello World!")
  ),

  # Server
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    # ... dealing with renderButton ...        
    addPopover(session=session, id="link", title="", 
               content="Testing.", placement = "bottom",
               trigger = "click", options = NULL)

  })
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer !! I was blocked using modal inside ValueBox feature. [Use href infobox as actionbutton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413137/use-href-infobox-as-actionbutton/34509153#34509153)