# Use href infobox as actionbutton

Tags: r, shiny, infobox, shinydashboard, action-button

I was building an `App` with `Rshiny`.

I have a couple of `infoBox`and I would like to use the `href` option to make a pop-up when clicking on the `infoBox`.

I use shinyBS for the popup options. 
here is what i tried :

```
valueBox(value=entry_01, icon = icon("users","fa-lg",lib="font-awesome"),href=shinyInput(actionLink,id='button_01',len=1,class="btn btn-default action-button",label=""),
        width=NULL,color = "light-blue",subtitle = ""
)
```

But I figured out that the `href` option work perfectly if we want to link on an external web site like `href = "http://stackoverflow.com/"`
but I didn't know how to link in an internal link of the app.

## EDIT

I make this edit because i found a solution which make the box clickable and make shiny think it was an action button, by adding two variable inside the valueBox output list.
- the class `action-button`
- The `id` which allow us to use observe or observeEvent to detect when the valuebox is clicked.

### Here is a reproductible example

```
require(shiny)
require(shinydashboard)


header <- dashboardHeader(title="ReproductibleExample")
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(disable=T)
body <- dashboardBody(valueBoxOutput("box_01"),
                      textOutput("print"))

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)


server<-shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  output$box_01 <- renderValueBox({
  entry_01<-20
  box1<-valueBox(value=entry_01
                 ,icon = icon("users",lib="font-awesome")
                 ,width=NULL
                 ,color = "blue"
                 ,href="#"
                 ,subtitle=HTML("<b>Test click on valueBox</b>")
                 )
    box1$children[[1]]$attribs$class<-"action-button"
    box1$children[[1]]$attribs$id<-"button_box_01"
    return(box1)
  })

  output$print<-renderText({
    print(input$button_box_01)
  })
})



shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I decided to change the method. I have now include an actionbutton (or actionLink) inside the substile element of the value box and create a bsModal element linked to this actionButton.
*If you are not familiar with the [ShinyBS](https://ebailey78.github.io/shinyBS/index.html) package it allow to make popover, tooltip etc features without including HTML or java.*

I follow the @Mikko Martila advice [Shiny: adding addPopover to actionLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31388329/shiny-adding-addpopover-to-actionlink) and here is a reproductile example to show you my issue :

```
library("shiny")
library("shinydashboard")
library("shinyBS")

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "reporductible example")

body <- dashboardBody(valueBoxOutput("box_01"),
                      bsModal("modal", "foo", trigger = "", "bar"))
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()
ui <- dashboardPage(header,sidebar,body,skin="green")
server = function(input, output, session) {
  # ----- First info box synthesis menu
  output$box_01 <- renderValueBox({
    entry_01 <- "BlaBla"
    valueBox(value=entry_01, icon = icon("users",lib="font-awesome"),
                    width=NULL,color = "blue",subtitle = HTML("<b>my substitle</b> <button id=\"button\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default action-button\">Show modal</button>")
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$button, {
    toggleModal(session, "modal", "open")
  })
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

I use the `HTML()` option to add my button inside the subtitle of value boxes.

It's not really what i wanted but it do the work.

You can do it with actionLink (it's look better) by using subtitle like this :

```
subtitle=HTML("<b>my subtitle</b><a id=\"button_box_05\" href=\"#\" class=\"action-button\">
     <i class=\"fa fa-question-circle\"></i>

       </a>")
```

Comment: This works great with modals but have you managed to display `shinyBS::addPopover` by clicking on the `valueBox`?

Answer (score 3):

I was stuck with the same problem and having gone through this link, just got it working, without adding a separate button, like this.
Hope this would help someone looking to solve a similar problem

```
require(shiny)
require(shinydashboard)
require(shinyBS)


header <- dashboardHeader(title="ReproductibleExample")
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(disable=T)
body <- dashboardBody(valueBoxOutput("box_01"),
                      textOutput("print"),bsModal("mod","title","btn"))

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)


server<-shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  output$box_01 <- renderValueBox({
  entry_01<-20
  box1<-valueBox(value=entry_01
                 ,icon = icon("users",lib="font-awesome")
                 ,width=NULL
                 ,color = "blue"
                 ,href="#"
                 ,subtitle=HTML("<b>Test click on valueBox</b>")
                 )
    box1$children[[1]]$attribs$class<-"action-button"
    box1$children[[1]]$attribs$id<-"button_box_01"
    return(box1)
  })
 observeEvent(input$button_box_01, {
  toggleModal(session,"mod","open")
  output$print<-renderText({
    print(input$button_box_01)
  })})
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: when i try this, my `observeEvent` isn't being triggered, any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

I know only bad variant

1) add function   `tags$script(HTML("function clickFunction(link){ 
                       Shiny.onInputChange('linkClicked',link);
    }"))`

2) edit href children of your valueBox

`aa=valueBox(value="22", icon = icon("users","fa-lg",lib="font-awesome"),href="www",
            width=NULL,color = "light-blue",subtitle = ""
)
aa$children[[1]]=a(href="#","onclick"=paste0("clickFunction('","click","'); return false;"),aa$children[[1]]$children)`

3)   `observeEvent(input$linkClicked,{..})`

Comment: i tried step by step and when i add the edit of childrend i have this error `Error in tagAssert(vbox, type = "div") : Expected tag to be of type div`

Comment: can you show? `aa=valueBox(value="22", icon = icon("users","fa-lg",lib="font-awesome"),href="www", width=NULL,color = "light-blue",subtitle = "" )` `print(aa)`

Comment: <div>
  <a href="www">
    <div class="small-box bg-light-blue">
      <div class="inner">
        <h3>41.5K</h3>
        <p>usagers en situation d'impayé</p>
      </div>
      <div class="icon-large">
        <i class="fa fa-users fa-lg"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

Comment: hmm.. dont know , show also `print(aa$children[[1]]$children)`

Comment: print(box_01$children[[1]]$children)
[[1]]
<div class="small-box bg-light-blue">
  <div class="inner">
    <h3>41.5K</h3>
    <p>usagers en situation d'impayé</p>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-large">
    <i class="fa fa-users fa-lg"></i>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: Well i will continu to search in that way i think your trik will help me a lot, il post something if i find the solution

Comment: how would you go about reproducing this for multiple boxes? also, why do you do
`clickFunction('","click","')`