# How to get conditionalPanel from clicking messageItem

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, shiny, shinydashboard

Inside shiny ui.R, while working with a `dashboardPage()`, my `dashboardHeader()` has a dropdown-menu referenced to a list:

```
dropdownMenu(type = "messages",.list=Mylist)
```

Where Mylist is filled with `messageItem()`'s.

But instead of using `dashboardBody()` and `tabItems()`, I'm using something like this:

```
tags$div(class="content-wrapper",
         conditionalPanel('condition',tags$section(...)))
         ,
         conditionalPanel('condition',tags$section(class="content",...))
         )
```

So that I could avoid the margins when creating a `leafletOutput()`.

My question is, how can I get my `conditionalPanel()` to use the click on any (or specific) message as a condition?

Same thing for `taskItems()` and `notificationItems()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're asking is: "How can I access the latest item (in a dropdown menu) that the user clicked?"

If that is the question, then I have to tell you that, unfortunately, shinydashboard doesn't support this (for now, at least). There is [an issue currently open](https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues/208) in shinydashboard's Github repo that would make this possible, but I can't tell you if/when we'd implement that... I'd recommend using a different condition mechanism (ideally something that is tracked by Shiny and accessible by `input$`). This is possible for the `sidebarMenu()`, which is made up of `menuItem()`s (as long as you provide an id to `sidebarMenu()` and a `tabName` to all the childless `menuItem()`s -- read more about that [here](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/behavior.html)). You said that you were not using `dashboardBody()` and `tabItems()` "so that I could avoid the margins when creating a leafletOutput()." I think it'd probably be a lot easier to handle the CSS for those cases, but stick to functionality provided by shinydashboard out of the box, than the reverse.

---

If you really want this, there is a workaround using the `href` argument of `messageItem()` (also present in `taskItem()` and `notificationItem()`). This is a bit clunky because you have to keep track of all the hrefs and you'd be updating the URL (in the example below, the hash), each time that you click on an item. If you do that though, now you have an event that you can listen to. However, you can't use conditional panels, since `getUrlHash()` must be called on the server (it needs to access the `session` object), not on the ui.

Again, this is a workaround. If you can, you should try to use a mechanic that is fully supported in shinydashboard (less chance of your app breaking or changing in future versions of the package).

Workaround using `href` argument to `messageItem`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# these must be unique and exist for every item
itemIds <- c(team = "#team", team2 = "#team2", user = "#user")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    dropdownMenu(type = "messages", badgeStatus = "success",
      messageItem("Support Team", "This is the content of a message.",
        time = "5 mins", href = itemIds[["team"]]
      ),
      messageItem("Support Team", "This is the content of another message.",
        time = "2 hours", href = itemIds[["team2"]]
      ),
      messageItem("New User", "Can I get some help?",
        time = "Today", href = itemIds[["user"]]
      )
    )
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    sliderInput("sld", "This is here so you know that other inputs are not affected by this workaround", 0, 100, 50),
    uiOutput("ui")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  output$ui <- renderUI({
    hash <- getUrlHash()
    if (hash %in% itemIds) {
      paste("This is shown when", hash, "is clicked")
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I found this yesterday and seemed easier to implement, https://stackoverflow.com/a/34449844/8042782