# shinydashboard's dropdownMenu event on click

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, sweetalert

Following this question and answer [Get the most recently clicked notificationItem of a dropdownmenu in shinydashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34418993/get-the-most-recently-clicked-notificationitem-of-a-dropdownmenu-in-shinydashboa)

I created the app below which nicely opens a sweetalert when clicking on a taskItem.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
ui <- fluidPage(
    dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(dropdownMenuOutput("dropdownmenu")),
        dashboardSidebar(),
        dashboardBody(
            tags$script(HTML("function clickFunction(link){ Shiny.onInputChange('linkClicked',link);}")),

    )))

server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
    output$dropdownmenu = renderMenu({

        aa <- 1:2 %>% 
           map(~taskItem(text = paste("This is no", .), value = ., color = c("red", "blue")[.]))

        for(i in 1:length(aa)){
            aa[[i]]$children[[1]] <- a(href="#","onclick"=paste0("clickFunction('",paste("This is no", i),"'); return false;"),
                                              aa[[i]]$children[[1]]$children)
        }
        dropdownMenu(type = "tasks", badgeStatus = "warning",
                     .list = aa)
    })


   observeEvent(input$linkClicked, {
        sendSweetAlert(
            session = session,
            text = input$linkClicked,
            type = "info",
            showCloseButton = TRUE)
    })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But hitting the same taskItem twice will not open the sweetalert again. It will only be opened again when hitting another item in between. How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a good article about that on the rstudio website: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-send-message.html.

**Root of the problem:**

> Caveat: **Shiny only listens for changes in the value of a message**.
>   Hence, if you call doAwesomeThing2 twice with the same arguments, the
>   second call will not trigger the observeEvent block because the object
>   you send is unchanged.

**Solution:**

> This can be **overcome by adding a random value
>   to your object**, which makes the object as a whole appear changed to
>   Shiny. In R, you simply ignore that part of the object....

So in your case you can change the code to:

```
tags$script(HTML("function clickFunction(link){
                      var rndm = Math.random();
                       Shiny.onInputChange('linkClicked', {data:link, nonce: Math.random()});}"
      ))
```

The call to the triggered input will be:

```
input$linkClicked$data
```

**Full reproducible example:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(dropdownMenuOutput("dropdownmenu")),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
      tags$script(HTML("function clickFunction(link){
                      var rndm = Math.random();
                       Shiny.onInputChange('linkClicked', {data:link, nonce: Math.random()});}"
      )),

    )))

server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  output$dropdownmenu = renderMenu({

    aa <- 1:2 %>% 
      map(~taskItem(text = paste("This is no", .), value = ., color = c("red", "blue")[.]))

    for(i in 1:length(aa)){
      aa[[i]]$children[[1]] <- a(href="#","onclick"=paste0("clickFunction('",paste("This is no", i),"'); return false;"),
                                 aa[[i]]$children[[1]]$children)
    }
    dropdownMenu(type = "tasks", badgeStatus = "warning",
                 .list = aa)
  })


  observeEvent(input$linkClicked, {
    sendSweetAlert(
      session = session,
      text = input$linkClicked$data,
      type = "info"
    )
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Note:

I assume you have the `sweetalert()` function from `shinyWidgets`, but i didnt have the possibility to add the `showCloseButton` parameter, so i removed it.

Comment: perfect. very nice! Have not found the post on that issue.