# In flexdashboard, can a valueBox be clicked to update a text box like an actionButton?

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I am trying to utilize `valueBox` in `flexdashboard` to display a headline figure. However, I also want the `valueBox` to act like an `actionButton`, in that clicking the `valueBox` should trigger an action elsewhere in the dashboard.

In checking the `flexdashboard` documentation, I see the following relevant bit for `valueBox`:

#### Linked Value Box

```
valueBox(42, icon = "fa-pencil", href="#details")
```

wherein clicking the `valueBox` will navigate the user to a different page with an anchor of "#details." However, there is nothing to indicate that clicking the `valueBox` could be used for other actions.

Below is a minimal relevant flexdashboard code

````
---
title: "valueBox Links"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)

    ```

Tab 1 - Test
======================================================================

Column 
-------------------------------------

#### Three valueBoxes

### valueBox 1
```{r}
valueBox(1)
    ```

### valueBox 2
```{r}
valueBox(2)
    ```

### valueBox 3
```{r}
valueBox(3)
    ```

Column
-------------------------------------

### Text output
This is where I want some text to show up dynamically, depending on if the user has clicked valueBox 1, 2, or 3.
````

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: This question might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413137/use-href-infobox-as-actionbutton

Comment: It is a good lead, but unfortunately it works with shinyDashboard. Unable to replicate it on flexDashboard.

Comment: What about making actionButtons that look like the valueBoxes?

Comment: I like that valueBoxes background colour and icon can be variable depending on the input value. Any way to replicate that with actionButtons?

Comment: Since its not a full answer, I made a small gist to show how to alter actionButtons in a shinyApp. [Gist example](https://gist.github.com/trafficonese/e0c695d617f412ff31ead9688ba6b80a)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I tried different parameters for `valueBox` without any luck. In the end I managed to solve it by putting `actionButton`s in the captions of the `valueBox`es, and then using custom styles to make them transparent and expand them so they cover the entire `valueBox`. It looks like this, where clicking each `valueBox` renders different text under "Text output":

[image]

I added color and icons to highlight that the `valueBox`es can be styled normally. It only uses the flexdashboard library, and it's completely responsive. Here's the code:

````
---
title: "valueBox Links"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

Tab 1 - Test
======================================================================

Column 
-------------------------------------

#### Three valueBoxes

### valueBox 1
```{r}
valueBox(1, caption = paste("I'm clickable!", actionButton("button1", " ", style = "background-color:rgba(39, 128, 227, 0.0); border-color:rgba(39, 128, 227, 0.0); position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; width:100%")), icon = "fa-thumbs-up", color = "success")
```

### valueBox 2
```{r}
valueBox(2, caption = paste("I'm clickable too!", actionButton("button2", " ", style = "background-color:rgba(39, 128, 227, 0.0); border-color:rgba(39, 128, 227, 0.0); position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; width:100%")), icon = "fa-tag", color = "warning")
```

### valueBox 3
```{r}
valueBox(3, caption = paste("ME TOO!", actionButton("button3", " ", style = "background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0); border-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0); position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; width:100%")), icon = "fa-random", color = "danger")
```

Column
-------------------------------------

### Text output
```{r}
textOutput("textout")

rv <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)

observeEvent(input$button1, {
rv$data <- "There are two types of people in the world: 1) Those who can extrapolate from incomplete data."
})

observeEvent(input$button2, {
rv$data <- "If you live to be one hundred, you’ve got it made. Very few people die past that age."
})

observeEvent(input$button3, {
rv$data <- "A statistician’s wife had twins. He was delighted. He rang the minister who was also delighted. “Bring them to church on Sunday and we’ll baptize them,” said the minister. “No,” replied the statistician. “Baptize one. We’ll keep the other as a control."
})  

output$textout <- renderText({
  rv$data
})
```
````